# Could not convert string to float error.

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to plot values onto the X and Y axis'. I do not want to put any data in the graph, just label the Axis' with **Time** and **DID**(As seen below)

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style 
style.use('ggplot')


df = pd.read_csv('Test_Sheet_1.csv')

Time = df.ix[8:, 1]

DID = df.ix[1, 6:13]


ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,6), (0,0), rowspan=1, colspan=6)

ax1.plot(Time)

plt.show()
```

and i receive this error:

```
Could not convert string to float.
```

yes what i am trying to put on the x, and y axis are letters, not numbers, so this error is valid. how do i fix this problem? Is there any easy way to plot these DID's and Times from the graph without getting this error?

Also, i am new to python, and coding in general, so if my question isnt clear please let me know, and i will try my best to fix it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think this is actually a matplotlib issue rather than a pandas one.

Comment: My guess is that you shouldn't plot `Time` but instead some dummy data and then make it invisible with `alpha=0`; then set the axis with `ax.set_xlabel` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The Time column may not be of type DateTime.

Will this work with an explicit conversion?

```
ax1.plot(pd.to_datetime(Time))
```