# convert string to float

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot values onto the X and Y axis'. I do not want to put any data in the graph, just label the Axis' with Time and DID(As seen below)

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style 
style.use('ggplot')


df = pd.read_csv('Test_Sheet_1.csv')

Time = df.ix[8:, 1]
print(Time)

DID = df.ix[1, 6:13]
print(DID)

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,6), (0,0), rowspan=6, colspan=6)

ax1.plot(Time)

plt.show()
```

and I receive this error:

```
could not convert string to float
```

What I am trying to put on the x and y axis are letters, not numbers, so this error is valid. How do I fix this problem? Is there any easy way to plot these DID's and Times from the graph without getting this error?

Also, I am new to python, and coding in general, so if my question isn't clear please let me know, and I will try my best to fix it.

Comment: What line is the error from?

Comment: I appreciate you didn't get an answer last time you asked this, but you still shouldn't duplicate your questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806027/could-not-convert-string-to-float-error

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that at this stage you do not want to put any data on the graph, do not use `plot`, because that is what `plot` is for.

In general, to customize the positions and labels of the x-axis ticks, you can set the `xticks` and `xticklabels` properties, respectively:

```
ax1.set(xticks=[0.33, 0.66], xticklabels=['abcd', 'efgh'])
plt.draw()
```

(Similarly, use `yticks` and `yticklabels` for the y-axis and `zticks` and `zticklabels` for the z-axis.)

More specifically if you're going to want to display data as a function of time/date, matplotlib has various higher-level library tools to help you render the dates nicely. [Here's an example.](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html)